# How to localize the flag menu in PHP?

Tags: php, localization

I have a multilingual site. The site has a locale flag menu that has links like these

`example.com/en/pages/more-info`
`example.com/fr/pages/plus-d-informations`
`example.com/de/pages/mehr-infos`
`example.com/pl/pages/więcej-informacji`

When user visits the particular page he sees that the whole page is localized for example in French. But the menu has to show every possible localization that is used by the website.

The question is: Should I use this code

```
putenv("LANG=" . $language); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language); 
bindtextdomain("messages", "Locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8'); 
textdomain("messages");
```

then

```
<a href="/fr/pages/<?=_("more-info")?>">French</a>
...
```

each time, to switch locale, when displaying each item in the flag menu?

`$language` changes before displaying each item in the flag menu.

Is it a correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the locale temporarily while when you iterate over your languages to print out alternate language links is a common practice.  I've done it on sites that I have worked on.

- Don't forget to save the "current locale" before you start and change the locale back to it after you are done with that code section.
- That does seem to be a lot of mechanics for switching the locale.  You'll want to encapsulate that in a function.
- As for performance, I'm not sure how your massages are stored, or if they are cached.  If you find that your approach is not performing well, it should be straightforward to add some mechanism for caching and fix it.